# How can I receive the persistence unit name of an EntityManager?

Tags: java, jpa, java-ee-5

In a Java EE application I am using @PersistenceContext on an EJB3.0 SessionBean to let an EntityManager be autowired.

As I am using multiple Datasources, I want to programmatically determine the autowired PersistenceUnit name of the EntityManager. Any chance?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve more than one entity manager in this way:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("name your PU")
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
...
em.close();
emf.close();
```

But I do not know if a good solution. Annotation @PersistenceContext allows retrieve only one entity manager. But you may try create one class/stateless bean which will keep more than one PU, and take from him PU which you need. Maybe this little better than use EntityManagerFactory.